# How to use CUDA IPC?

Tags: cuda

I am newbie to CUDA and learning to use CUDA IPC for my project. Regarding the CUDA example [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/simpleIPC/simpleIPC.cu#L234): How does the program know the number of shm->nprocesses?

Answer (score 1):

That variable is initially set to zero via the `memset` operation [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/simpleIPC/simpleIPC.cu#L203).

After that, the only place it is modified is [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/simpleIPC/simpleIPC.cu#L255), which if you trace the code, will be executed/incremented once per device found that satisfies the peer clique requirement and other requirements needed by the test.  The overall loop that is checking each device starts [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/simpleIPC/simpleIPC.cu#L209).

Comment: Thanks Robert. You always help us on CUDA questions. One more question, in this line, shm->devices[shm->nprocesses++] = i; in the first loop, it first assigns shm->device[0] and then increases nprocesses to ->1. Right?

Comment: yes, in the C or C++ language, `var++` is a ["postincrement" operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pre-increment-and-post-increment-concept-in-c-cplusplus).  The expression is evaluated with the variable at its current value, then the variable is incremented.

Comment: Thanks Robert again.